# How can i check mail sending is allowed in client's server

Tags: php, sendmail

In my site there have some mailing options.Here iam sending an html mails.
So i need to check wheather my client's server support the mail function or not.
How can i check this?
If there is any php code for this ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this? Sending E-Mail can be allowed but the server can be misconfigured so no E-Mail will be sent anyway, rendering your check pointless. What is your actual situation?

Comment: i want to check mail() is supporting into client's server?

Comment: as said, being able to call `mail()` doesn't necessarily mean E-Mail is set up. This stuff is complex, there is no single check to find out. The best thing would be to send an actual E-Mail and see whether it arrives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so `you want to check mail() is supporting into client's server?`

```
if(function_exists('mail'))
{

}
```

But, i'm sure this method is not recommended, the best way to check, send an empty message to your self:

```
<?php
if(mail($to,$subject,$message) != false)
{
   echo 'You can send email';
}
?>
```

Comment: but when iam using this code an error message is displayed "Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in E:\wamp\www\promo\install\index.php on line 108"

Answer (score 1):

You can only check whether mail is sent or not:

```
$message = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";

// Send
if(mail('YOUR_EMAIL_HERE@example.com', 'My Subject', $message)) {
  echo "Sent";
}
else {
  echo "Not Sent";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
if(mail('TEST_ACCOUNT@gmail.com','test','content') != false)
{
   echo 'You can send email from this server';
}else{
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
```